# Ruby Activerecord IN clause

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I was wondering if anyone knew how to do an "IN" clause in activerecord.  Unfortunately, the "IN" clause is pretty much un-googleable so I have to post here.  Basically I want to answer a question like this "Give me all the college students that are in these dormitories where the dormitory id is in this array [id array]".  I know how to write the query given a single dormitory id, but I don't know how to do it given an array of ids.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm sure this is a repost of a question somewhere, so I'll delete this once an answer/better search term is found.

Comment: On the contrary: This page was the top result on a Google search for "activerecord in". ;-)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

From [§3.3.3 Subset Conditions of the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions):

> If you want to find records using the `IN` expression you can pass an
> array to the conditions hash:
>
> ```rb
> Customer.where(orders_count: [1,3,5])
> ```
>
> This code will generate SQL like this:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT * FROM customers WHERE
> (customers.orders_count IN (1,3,5))
> ```

You can also use the [arel](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/Nodes/In) syntax:

```
Client.where(Client.arel_table[:order_count].in([1,3,5]))
```

will generate the same SQL.

Comment: it may be worth noting the problems this has with empty arrays.