# Set intersection or Join more efficient? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

So my Group model has a bunch of Members, some members are friends with one another, some aren't. I'd like to create a controller action that a user can make a request to via my app, that gives back a hash like the following:

```
{ group : { members: { friends: group_friends, others: group_others } } }
```

I've accomplished the following via a set intersection in ruby:

```
group_members = group.all_members
user_friends = current_user.all_friends
user_group_friends = group_members & user_friends
user_group_others = group_members - user_group_friends
```

My question is, being that this is ruby - would a database query utilizing a join be a better option here in terms of performance? Or should I just leave this as is....

I'm also curious as to what a query would look like for this...

FYI: These are the relationships I'm working with:

```
  Group
    has_many :members, class_name: "User"
    has_many :inverse_members....
    # all_members retrieves members who have added, been added

  User
    has_many :user_groups
    has_many :groups, :through => :user_groups
    has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, :through => friendships
    has_many :inverse_friends....
    ....
    # all_friends retrieves all friends who have added, been added

  User_Groups
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group

  Friendship
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend
```

### Queries so far:

### #1

```
group_members = group.all_members # Instance method uses returns associated members
group_members_friends = group_members.where("? in friends OR ? in inverse_friends", current_user, current_user)
```

Gives this error

```
     # --- Caused by: ---
 # SQLite3::SQLException:
 #   no such table: friends

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: friends: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_groups" ON "users"."id" = "user_groups"."user_id" WHERE "user_groups"."group_id" = ? AND (1 in friends OR 1 in inverse_friends)
```

because the join that allows group.all_members to happen (User_Groups) does not contain the field friends (obviously via the above associations)... How do I get access to the each member(User) in question and check their friends??

### #2

```
group_members = group.all_members # Instance method uses returns associated members
group_members_friends = group_members.where("id in ?", current_user.all_friends)
```

Gives this error:

```
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # SQLite3::SQLException:
 #   near "2": syntax error

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: near "2": syntax error: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_groups" ON "users"."id" = "user_groups"."user_id" WHERE "user_groups"."group_id" = ? AND (user.id in 2,3)
```

Comment: You have two questions here. One is about performance, and there are already answers to that. The second is how to implement with a join query. I think this is another topic, and there is a lot on SO and internet about that. What have you tried? Before answering, you may need to edit and fork another question, but again, I believe there are already quite a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main points to know when assessing wether the database will be faster:

1. Executing a query on a database is really fast (usually, when set up right).
2. Ruby is relatively slow.
3. What can be time consuming is MANY round trips to the database (hence the advice to [avoid N+1 queries](http://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/)). It's not that the time taken to execute each query is a lot - it's the round trips from Ruby to the database that add up.
4. Because of points 1 and 2, If you want performance, it's almost always a good decision to defer whatever logic you can to the database, rather than ruby
5. "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil". So, if what you're doing is working, don't worry about it until you have a performance problem.

Now, applying this to your situation: At this point, you've only got a few separate queries, so you're OK regarding point 3. And you haven't mentioned performance problems so far, so you're probably fine re: point 5, and should just leave it as is.

But if you want to proceed with (possibly premature) optimisation:

**Regarding point 4 - are you deferring logic to the database or not?**

Well, if you look at the methods you're using from `ActiveRecord::Relation`, they're actually just delegated to `records`. (You can find this by doing eg. `group_members.all.method(:-).source_location` then looking at the source code). Now, checking what `:recrods` is by running `group_members.records.class.name`, you get `Array` - that is, the `-` and `&` methods are acting on a Ruby array of results - so, that means the subtraction / addition logic is taking place in Ruby, and is NOT being deferred to the database. This means it's potentially slow if you're dealing with a LOT of results.

In terms of changing that, the initial hunch may be to try and get ALL results back in one query - but this is a bad idea because you will then still have to filter through them with Ruby, one by one, instantiating many ruby objects, to place them into their respective categories. So the logic here still takes place in ruby.

If you wanted to optimise for performance, what you'd do is have 4 database queries - one for each category - but have each query return the entire result set for that category, to avoid you doing `group_members & user_friends` or similar in Ruby.

This is just pseudocode and I have no idea about your domain, but something like:

```
# user_group_friends = group_members & user_friends
# REPLACE WITH:
user_group_friends = Friend.where('is_group_member = ? AND is_user_friend = ?', true, true)
```

... and you'd do that for each category.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I definitely want to optimize for performance. Do you mind giving an example of how I would make these 4 queries and join them to get my desired result?

Comment: +1 for the premature optimization point. A naive implementation can still "be enough", depending on the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Don't "join" the 4 queries per se. Leave them as 4 separate queries - just make each one a single SQL statement that returns exactly what you want for that category. I've given a pseudo-example of that. You know your domain model better than me, so hopefully you can apply it to your specific situation based on that info.

Comment: @joshua.paling thanks, I added the associations I'm working with to my question

Comment: @EricPlaton At maximum scale I'm expecting no more than high hundreds of friends per user as well as members in a group, but this would come with high traffic which means I want to optimize response time

Comment: @Riptyde4 have a crack at writing those 4 queries yourself, and if you get stuck, update your answer with your progress so far and we can help you from there.

Comment: Also, at high-hundreds, I'd say leave it as is. At this point it's more important that you use your limited time to build other features to make your app more successful. If success comes and traffic is high - great! Then put some time into performance optimisation at that point, and it'll be easier to tell if what you do has had the impact you needed.

Comment: @joshua.paling I've been stuck on that for quite a while hence reaosning behind posting that part of my question: What makes it difficult is that the conditional inside the for `Group.attendees.where('...')` would have to come from whether there exists a row inside of the Friendship table that maps the current user's id to the attendee's id -> I can't find a single thing online referencing a similar scenario.  It would have to be something like `Group.attendees.where(current_user.friends include? current_attendee)` which is obviously psuedocode, I'm just unsure how to join the two in this way

Comment: @joshua.paling Regarding holding off, I'm close to doing that because I will most likely be moving to a graph database (neo4j) considering the nature of my app, but this is good stuff to know so I figured i'd give it a shot

Comment: Regarding the `Group.attendees.where(current_user.friends include? current_attendee)`, what you're after is SQL's `IN` clause. There's lots about this online eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181864/ruby-activerecord-in-clause

Comment: The first step is to get it working in plain SQL, and the convert it to use Active Record. If you have questions about the SQL implementation, I'd say you're best off opening a new question specifically on that - ignoring the ruby details and just describing your database structure, and what  you want to get from it.

Comment: @joshua.paling Alright, thanks, I'll look into that. I guess I wasn't searching with the correct keywords!

Comment: Yeah, always tricky to search when you're not even sure what exactly to search for! Good luck!

Comment: @joshua.paling Still stuck unfortunately :( I updated my question with one of the queries I tried, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Have to finish something at work right now but will try take a look over the weekend.

Comment: Just at first glance, `current_user.all_friends` will return an instance of ActiveRelation, and what you want is an array of id's. So try something like: `group_members_friends = group_members.where("id in ?", current_user.all_friends.pluck(:id))`

Comment: Also, I wrote something a while back which I think may be relevant to you: http://joshuapaling.com/blog/2014/05/07/superstition-driven-development.html I'd recommend trying to put time into better grasping the building blocks in ruby and rails. The time spent will be well worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

The database engine is most likely to be much faster than Ruby on such kind of query. Join operations are provided directly by the engines, so they do feature years of optimizations in the native language.

Even if the calling language was compiled (e.g. Java or C++), I think it would still be faster to rely on the engine's implementation of the join operation. As a rule of thumb, the engine and its engineers are *clever* than the caller most of the time (first because they are *in*).

---

I have no relation to Alexander Dymo, but I recommend his book [Ruby Performance Optimization](https://pragprog.com/book/adrpo/ruby-performance-optimization) for tips, benchmarks, and others on such kind of question. He addresses that very point, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the info, just as I thought.  Can you offer any info on how to formulate this query?